# How to do numerical integration with pytorch similar to numpy's trapz function?

Tags: python, pytorch, numerical-integration

Title says it all. Is there a convenient function in pytorch that can do something like `np.trapz(y, x)` (integrating over the the points in `x` and `y` via trapezoidal rule)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in tool for that, but it should not be difficult to implement it yourself, especially using the [numpy code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3982-L4070) as a guideline.

Answer (score 5):

Since pytorch version 1.2 a native [trapz function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=trapz#torch.trapz) has been introduced.